# Income taxes - Changing state of residence before moving out of the US

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement, state-income-tax, california

I'm an European citizen working for in the US with a 2 year contract; I was and will be a non resident alien for 2020 and 2021, but RA in 2022; I *have* to contribute to a retirement fund (it's a 401(a), basically identical to a 401(k)).

If I move out of the US after this experience, and would like to withdraw the money out of my retirement plan, would I have to pay federal + state taxes, or only federal since I won't have any tie to a specific US state? Is the last state where I had an address the one used to calculate state income taxes?
Are there laws against changing address to another state with a lower income tax before moving out of the US indefinitely?

My question is a mix of these two:

- [Withdraw from 401(k) after moving out of the U.S. with lower taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/75463/)
- [Is it legal to move to a different US state before moving out of the country to avoid paying state income tax abroad?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/108209/) - but I'm not a US citizen and the question asks about income taxes on current salary, not retirement